# IBM Domino: first time view load slowly after view.refresh

Tags: lotus-domino

I have a scheduled agent to refresh view (`view.refresh`). But after the agent finishes, the first time to load view is slow, and then load view quickly. I saw the guide document said

> This method (notesview.refresh) does not refresh the front-end view that the interactive user sees, nor does it rebuild the front-end view. See ViewRefresh and ViewRebuild in NotesUIWorkspace.

So I try to use

```
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Call workspace.ViewRefresh
```

but I get "Error creating product object". It seems like workspace is front end object. So how can I avoid first time load slowly after `view.refresh`?

Comment: Refreshing the view on the server means that all cached data on every client is invalidated. There's going to be a delay when the client opens the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said view.refresh will refresh the index of the view (B-TREE).
If you experiment a delay when opening in UI (front-end) and want to "programmatically" open it you can't do this server side but only client side.

I suggest you to add a simple agent that whill actually open this view in the client for example with

```
Call notesUIWorkspace.OpenDatabase( server$, file$, view$, key$, newInstance, temp )
```

Schedule this agent in you **client**, the help explains how to do: [Triggering an agent on a schedule](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTWP_9.0.0/com.ibm.notes900.help.doc/agt_trigger_agent_on_schedule_t.html)

Comment: The index might be regenerated when openin the view server-side and executing a getDocumentByKey. Never tried this though...

Comment: Thanks for your response! There is an option named "On Refresh" in view's option. Are there any different between "Display indicator" and "Refresh display" when I try to load view from web(like http://test/test.nsf/testview?openview)?

Comment: When you open the view in Notes client, the view is refreshed and displayed... unless Refresh time options of the view is MANUAL (check in your case that it is **not** on manual). After the view is open, any further change on document won't be displayed if you selected "Display indicator" in the Refresh display options. In your case you can improve you client agent by selecting "Refresh display from top row" in the Refresh display options of the view.